# VB.NET - How to copy file first before it move by the other services

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

We have a existing windows service that move the files (7 files, 5 *event.xdf, 1 statistics.xdf, and 1 order.xdf files) and translate it into xml.

I created a windows service that copy all the 7 files before it move by the other Windows services. I can only copy 3 *event.xdf, 1 statistics.xdf and 1 order.xdf.

I miss 2 event.xdf.

Here is my logic for code

I create a thread for each distinct file and copy each.

Copy event to temp folder:

```vb
thXDFevent = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf backup_xdf_events)
thXDFevent.IsBackground = True
thXDFevent.Start()

'order
thXDForder = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf backup_xdf_order)
thXDForder.IsBackground = True
thXDForder.Start()

'statistics
thXDFstatistics = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf backup_xdf_statistics)
thXDFstatistics.IsBackground = True
thXDFstatistics.Start()
```

Functions:

```vb
Private Sub backup_xdf_events()
        Try
            While (True)
                getXDFevents()
            End While
        Catch ex As Exception
            'EventLog1.WriteEntry("Services XDF error:" & strDate.ToString)
        End Try
 End Sub

Private Sub getXDFevents()
    Dim f As String
    For Each f In Directory.GetFiles("C:\POS\", "*event.xdf")

        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile("C:\POS\" & Path.GetFileName(f), xdf_temp & Path.GetFileName(f), True)
    Next f
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
End Sub

Private Sub backup_xdf_order()
    Try
        While (True)
            getXDForder()
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception
        'EventLog1.WriteEntry("Services XDF error:" & strDate.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub getXDForder()
    Dim f As String
    For Each f In Directory.GetFiles("C:\POS\", "*order.xdf")

        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile("C:\POS\" & Path.GetFileName(f), xdf_temp & Path.GetFileName(f), True)
    Next f
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
End Sub

Private Sub backup_xdf_statistics()
    Try
        While (True)
            getXDFstatistics()
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception
        'EventLog1.WriteEntry("Services XDF error:" & strDate.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub


Private Sub getXDFstatistics()
    Dim f As String
    For Each f In Directory.GetFiles("C:\POS\", "*statistics.xdf")

        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile("C:\POS\" & Path.GetFileName(f), xdf_temp & Path.GetFileName(f), True)
    Next f
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
End Sub
```

Comment: Isn't this exactly what [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternate approach using [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and Tasks to copy the file as soon as it's available.

`Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = True` would go in your service OnStart.

```
Module Module1

    Private WithEvents Watcher As New IO.FileSystemWatcher("C:\POS", "*.xdf")

    Private Const xdf_temp As String = "c:\pos\temp"

    Sub Main()
        Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = True

        Console.WriteLine("Watching . . .")
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Watcher_Created(sender As Object, e As IO.FileSystemEventArgs) Handles Watcher.Created
        Select Case True
            Case e.FullPath.EndsWith("event.xdf")
                Task.Run(Sub() CopyFile(e.FullPath))
            Case e.FullPath.EndsWith("statistics.xdf")
                Task.Run(Sub() CopyFile(e.FullPath))
            Case e.FullPath.EndsWith("order.xdf")
                Task.Run(Sub() CopyFile(e.FullPath))
        End Select
    End Sub

    Private Sub CopyFile(FullPath As String)
        Dim Timeout As New Stopwatch
        Dim Success As Boolean = False

        Timeout.Restart()

        Do Until Success Or Timeout.Elapsed.Minutes > 0
            Try
                IO.File.Copy(FullPath, IO.Path.Combine(xdf_temp, IO.Path.GetFileName(FullPath)), True)
                Success = True
            Catch
                ' File Not accessible...locked, write in progress, etc.
                Threading.Thread.Sleep(New TimeSpan(0, 0, 1))
            End Try
        Loop

        If Not Success Then
            'Timeout expired - write something in an event log
        End If
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Thank you So much sir! I just added the AddHandler Watcher.Created, AddressOf Watcher_created. also the select case does not work. also, There are times that the files are complete and times that I still miss 1 or 2 files.

Comment: Yep, you have to do that if you don't instantiate it using `WithEvents` and auto-generated the handlers.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer by clicking the checkmark to the left.